# Why is x:key required on ControlTemplate in the ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate, resourcedictionary

Consider the following XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="ExpressionVisualizer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sle="clr-namespace:System.Linq.Expressions;assembly=System.Core"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sle:BinaryExpression}"/>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}"/>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

This is giving the following compile error:

> All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some
>   other type of key associated with them. Line 10 Position 10.

If I add an `x:key` attribute to the ControlTemplate, it compiles. However, I should not have to do that. The ControlTemplate is decorated with the DictionaryKeyProperty attribute which specifies TargetType as the key property. So as long as I specify a TargetType for my ControlTemplate, I should **not** have to specify an explicit key (similar to how I don't have to specify one on the DataTemplate I've defined).

I have a second and tangentially related question. If I define a ControlTemplate in this way (either specifying a key or not) in the XAML, does it get automatically applied to all controls of type ContentControl that don't specify another template, or would I have to embed the ControlTemplate inside a Style for that to occur?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From MSDN [ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.targettype.aspx):

> If you have a standalone ControlTemplate in the resources section with
>   the TargetType property set to a type, the ControlTemplate does not
>   get applied to that type automatically. Instead, you need to specify
>   an x:Key and apply the template explicitly.
>
> Also note that the TargetType property is required on a ControlTemplate if the template
>   definition contains a ContentPresenter.

So the `ControlTemplate` is not automatically applied and you have to always specify the `x:Key`. So the `DictionaryKeyProperty` doesn't apply.

I did some research:

Although the [DictionaryKeyPropertyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.dictionarykeypropertyattribute.aspx) MSDN page states:

> WPF Usage Notes
>
> The following list references examples of WPF APIs where this
>   attribute is applied:
>
> ```
> ControlTemplate.TargetType
>
> DataTemplate.DataTemplateKey
>
> Style.TargetType
> ```

But on the [Resources Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx) page they only mention `Styles, DataTemplates, and Implicit Keys` which has implicit keys. This also implies that you need to always specify the `x:Key` for `ControlTemplate` despite the `DictionaryKeyProperty`.

By the way it seems there is something wrong with the `DictionaryKeyPropertyAttirubte` see this [connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/426549/compile-time-error-for-xaml-resource-dictionaries-adding-classes-marked-with-dictionarykeypropertyattribute).

Comment: That answers the second part of my question. I know I need to specify an x:Key if I want to reference the template elsewhere in the document, but omitting it should not cause a compile error.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It seams `DictionaryKeyProperty` is not doing what it should be...

Comment: The problem with DictionaryKeyProperty appears not to affect all types, since the attribute works as specified on DataTemplate. The Connect issue is from 2009. I guess I'll just write this off as yet another thing in WPF that just doesn't work and was never thoroughly tested. Every time I try to develop something in WPF I run into these types of issues. This never occurs with Windows Forms, everything just works. I really thought (perhaps wishfully) that they were going to make WPF more predictable/usable in the 4.0 release.

Comment: @nemesv, the Microsoft connect has been "retired"-- the link is now dead

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer to your first question, but about the second:

> I have a second and tangentially related question. If I define a
>   ControlTemplate in this way (either specifying a key or not) in the
>   XAML, does it get automatically applied to all controls of type
>   ContentControl that don't specify another template, or would I have to
>   embed the ControlTemplate inside a Style for that to occur?

No, it won't be automatically applied. Styles get applied automatically if their key matches the `DefaultStyleKey` of the control; data templates are picked up automatically by a `ContentControl` if the type of the `Content` matches the `DataType` of the template. But it's not the case for control templates ; anyway, control templates are usually defined as part of a control's style, they are rarely applied directly to a control.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the control template will be applied to all specified type you can define a style and set Template property and that style with TargetType to your specified control:

```
<Window x:Class="ExpressionVisualizer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sle="clr-namespace:System.Linq.Expressions;assembly=System.Core"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DT" DataType="{x:Type sle:BinaryExpression}"/>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="CT" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}"/>
    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource  CT}"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

I've tested this with a button targettype but I think it should work in that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window x:Class="ExpressionVisualizer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sle="clr-namespace:System.Linq.Expressions;assembly=System.Core"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DT" DataType="{x:Type sle:BinaryExpression}"/>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="CT" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Key is used to apply templating on control like as button, textbox, textblock etc. If you don't use it then templating is not working.